# How can I use existing ASP.NET Membership data in a new .Net Core project?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-membership, asp.net-core-identity

I am starting a new .Net Core Web application. And I want to use the authentication tables (aspnet_Users, aspnet_Membership etc) that already exist in our database. But I am not sure how to do it.

Upon creating the project, I select "Individual User Accounts" option for authentication. Then I need to choose between "Store user accounts in-app" and "Connect to existing store in the cloud".

It seems like none of them suits my need.

Comment: You're asking how to migrate existing accounts from ASP.NET Membership, the old authentication and profile features, to ASP.NET Core Identity. You can't just use the same tables, the table design and security features have changed a lot.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I read that it is still supported in .Net Core for compatibility...

Comment: Where did you read that? Not in the *options*, either the command-line options, or the UI Wizard. In any case, ASP.NET Core uses a very different version of ASP.NET Identity than the one used by ASP.NET MVC, which in turn is very different from ASP.NET Membership

Comment: The migration procedure is described in [Migrate from ASP.NET Membership authentication to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos "ASP.Net Core in Action" says, "Earlier versions of Asp.Net used a role-based approach to security rather than claims-based. The ClaimsPrincipal used in ASP.NET Core is compatible with this approach for legacy reasons, but you should use the claims-based approach for new apps."

The same users are used in existing applications, so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: As the book says `you should use the claims-based approach for new apps`. There's no reason to use the old *API* and any incompatibilities when all you need is the old data. In ASP.NET 2.0 the assumption was that HttpContext would always be available as static static. This doesn't work any more so even MVC code that used Identity [needs tweaking now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to remove the static references

Comment: "As the book says you should use the claims-based approach for new apps. There's no reason to use the old API and any incompatibilities when all you need is the old data."

But I have old applications that still use the data in the existing tables. It would require to rewrite a huge amount of code to use the new approach... That is what makes me desperate about migrating...

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos And most of the projects are not MVC, but WebForms.

Comment: @DavidShochet Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @mattumotu I just had to use the new tables and migrate the data using a script I found somewhere by googling. The passwords are lost though.