# How to add authentication to a .Net Core 2 application using old authentication data?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an MVC Core 2.1 application. Now I need to add authentication (and authorization) to it, but I need to use user membership data used by our old applications (tables aspnet_Users, aspnet_Membership etc). 
I have already asked similar question before ([How can I use existing ASP.NET Membership data in a new .Net Core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275103/how-can-i-use-existing-asp-net-membership-data-in-a-new-net-core-project)), but did not receive an answer.

Comment: Couldn't you upgrade it to asp.net core 2.2 and then scaffold the identity onto it?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: For `AspNetIdentity` and `AspNetCore Identity`, they are following different design, you could not use AspNet Core Identity with existing old tables. Try to migrate the [AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity) to .net core version, and add it to your project.

Comment: @Tao Zhou As I mentioned, other application use the same user data, so I would need to have user data in to places... I doubt it would be correct, right?

Comment: @Matt Luccas Phaure Jensen But how migrating to .net core 2.2 can help me use old tables with user data? Actually, I am using 2.1, not 2.0, sorry.

Comment: @DavidShochet Ah, I misunderstood you, as far as I see there is no easy way to do this, I would personally implement the 2.1 identitymodel and database, and then run an sql script to migrate the old data to the correct places and formats on the new database. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @Matt Luccas Phaure Jensen Thank you anyway :)

Comment: For `aspnet_Users`, I assume it uses old aspnet identity. Check which library you used in other application, and try to convert the library to .net core version which could be referenced in mvc core. There is no built-in way to configure .net core to use existing table. You need to implement the logic by yourself with your table and logic design.

Comment: @Tao Zhou Thank you for your answer. I would be too complicated though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS posted a howto just recently. It doesn't do what you want directly, instead it migrates data to the new tables. I don't think you can use the old tables without some custom code as the data types and names have changed and the hash algorithms for the password field is different too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Thank you for this!